# Empty benchmarks when running JMH samples in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jmh

I have some problem with using JMH.

So, I create an empty project in Intellij Idea, then in project structure add [jmh-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.jmh/jmh-core) jar file. Finally, try to run samples, for example

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.GenerateMicroBenchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

public class JMHSample_01_HelloWorld {
    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void wellHelloThere() {
        // this method was intentionally left blank.
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(".*" + JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.class.getSimpleName() + ".*")
                .forks(1)
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

}
```

but result is

```
No matching benchmarks. Miss-spelled regexp?
Use EXTRA verbose mode to debug the pattern matching.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

with using `verbosity(VerboseMode.EXTRA)`

```
No matching benchmarks. Miss-spelled regexp?
Benchmarks: 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried to change output path to `projectFolder\target\classes` but nothing was changed.
Then I looked at the source code in the debug mode and see that `resource = "/META-INF/MicroBenchmarks"`,`urls.hasMoreElements()` is false and therefore `benchmarks` is empty. Then I saw at the samples jar file which has MicroBenchmarks file with information about tests and work well.

So, the question is what do I do wrong?
Do I have to write information about test manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow the instructions on JMH page to set up the benchmark project, namely:

> "Make sure you tried these things before getting support:
>   - **Archetypes provide the golden build configuration.** Try to generate the clean JMH benchmark project and transplant the benchmark
>   there. This is important to try when upgrading to the newer JMH
>   versions, since the minute differences in the build configurations may
>   attribute to the failures you are seeing."

If you'd follow that, you will notice that you also need to add **jmh-generator-annprocess** as the dependency, and make sure it runs before you run any test.